# Ошибка компиляции: Error CS0117: does not contain a > definition for 'barSize' (CS0117)

Tags: android, c#, google-play, xamarin

Сегодня обновился Google Play Services и Android SDK. Не могу скомпилировать проект. Выдается 34 ошибки

Одна из них

> C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Murakami_kiev\MurakamiKiev\Resources\Resource.designer.cs(100,100):
>   Error CS0117: 'MurakamiKiev.Resource.Attribute' does not contain a
>   definition for 'barSize' (CS0117) (MurakamiKiev)

Все ошибки висят в *Resource.designer.cs*. Кто то знает как исправить? Вчера все работало, код за сегодня не менялся.

global::GooglePlayServices.Resource.Styleable.View_backgroundTint = global::MurakamiKiev.Resource.Styleable.View_backgroundTint;
            global::GooglePlayServices.Resource.Styleable.View_backgroundTintMode = global::MurakamiKiev.Resource.Styleable.View_backgroundTintMode;

Например тут выскакивают ошибки, но до этого туда не лез и все работало

Comment: Даблклик по ошибке должен открыть файл дизайнера в виде текста.

Comment: открыл
ошибка гугл плея

или запостить сюда строку в которой ошибка? @Qwertiy

Comment: Попытаться исправить, возможно, удалить. Хотя и в вопрос добавить не повредит.

Comment: Добавил @Qwertiy